# Rashi, Yebamoth 55b:7

Tags: rashi, translation, talmud-bavli, masechet-yevamot

Is my translation of [this Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Yevamot.55b.7?lang=bi) on Yevamot correct?

> It deals with impurity due to contact with a dead body - in case a man
> has sex with his dead wife it is not impurity because the latter is
> always to be considered as a relative of her.

Comment: Are you asking if you translated it correctly, or if there are any errors in the writing of Rashi?

Comment: Yes, if the translation is correct,

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106675/9215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rashi is explaining that one might have mistakenly thought that if one had relations with someone else’s deceased wife, he would be held guilty for committing adultery, being that she still has the status of being his wife, like we find in the laws of a priest becoming impure, that he is allowed to become impure by his deceased wife, like by the other relatives, and that’s why the Torah needs to tell us that in this case, he would nevertheless not be held liable for adultery

Comment: Yes. So my translation is correct?